# Should I say "in the world" or "on the world"?

Tags: prepositions

For instance in the following sentence is it correct to say "on the world" or "in the world"?

> "This is the biggest animal on / in the world"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should say either "in the world" or  "on the planet". Saying "on the world" would sound strange.

So your choices are:

> This is the biggest animal in the world.
>
> or
>
> This is the biggest animal on the planet.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The same thing here:
http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic10386.html